# Applet/Web Start securtiy

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp

I have this serious confusion on Security for Applets and apps deployed using Web Start.

My questions are, should I **also** update the policy file or create a user defined policy file when I,

1. sign the jar files of my Applet in order to access client resources like saving and reading files?
2. use JNLP and sign the jar files of my app to deploy using web start?
3. Also, when should I extend the SecurityManager class and use my own security manager?

I have seen some examples in the internet where someone mentioned about updating the policy file or create a user defined policy file and make the Security Manager use this user defined policy file or use it as part JVM argument.....not sure what that meant!

Comment: *"should I **also** update the policy file or create a user defined policy file"*  No.  Don't touch the policy file at all.  Digitally sign the applet Jar.

Comment: @Andrew...not even create a user defined policy file which will be different from the default policy file?

Comment: *"not even create a user defined policy"*  Not then, not ever.

Comment: @AndrewThompson...so just by signing the jar file (for applets), I will be able to perform default resrticted actions like read and copy from user's computer?

Comment: signing the jar is one of the necessary conditions for performing restricted actions - but it's not a sufficient condition.

Comment: @AndrewThompson....thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the developer of the Applet or Web Start application you should never touch the policy file.
The policy file is a kind of tool that allows the administrator of a machine to enforce the security policies defined for this machine. As the developer of the applet you might not even know these policies.
By relying on a updated policy file you would force your clients to change their policies according to your needs.

As the developer you can only react on these restrictions but you cannot change them.
Of course, a possible reaction may be to refuse the execution and print a message indicating that the application cannot be executed under the given restrictions.

Comment: @mschenk74...Thanks for your reply. So when should we extend the SecurityManager class?

Comment: What do you mean by "extend the SecurityManager class"? Do you want to achieve less restrictions? Then, the answer is also "don't do it" - with nearly the same argumentation: a SecurityManager is the class that enforces the security policies defined. If you want to add more restrictions, then a custom SecurityManager may be one component to achieve that.